# Axios error axios.get() error ERR BAD REQUEST how to fix it

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

[My feed.jsx file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLaZJ.png)

[this is my error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOKgl.png)

Comment: please post your code as text

Comment: Pass it as full URL of the backend. `http://localhost:[PORT OF BACKEND]/posts/timeline/***`

Comment: you can add this line : `axios.defaults.baseUrl = "http://localhost:BACKEND-PORT/`

Comment: [Please post code and errors as formatted text rather than links to images of formatted text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/438992)

Comment: It’s a 404; it can be fixed by making a request to a URL that exists with a method the URL accepts.

Comment: @dom1 The error from Axios already contains the host/port. It’s a good idea to be explicit, but it doesn’t cause the error.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, but the host/port belong to the frontend not backend.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe due to bad error connection or your's URL is not correct.